# FirebaseFirestore stops working in Flutter after app is sent to background

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm listening to a FirebaseFirestore stream to monitor DB changes and reflect them in my Flutter application. Everything works fine initially - however, when I send the app to background for 1+ hrs and open it up again, the stream stops working completely. I'm unable to fetch new data [tested this by updating my Firebase collection / document manually] or write data back to the DB. Note that the app UI looks fine - it's only the flow of data that stops working

I understand that the OS might be killing my stream to preserve resources, which makes sense. How should I go about reestablishing the Firebase connection? Should I detect the app lifecyle and pause / resume the listener accordingly OR should I remove the listener when the app is sent to background and create a new Firebase connection whenever the app is brought to foreground? I'm new to Flutter / Firebase so trying to understand the best practice over here. Thanks in advance!

I've been able to reproduce this issue consistently and can confirm that the this is not cause by any authentication related errors.

Here's a snippet of an example Firebase call from the app:

```
try {
 return FirebaseFirestore
   .instance
   .collection("endTime")
   .doc("docId")
          .snapshots()
          .listen((result) {
        setState(() {
          timeToNextMatch = result.data()['timeToNextMatch'];

          isLoading = false;
        });
      }).onError((e) => debugPrint("TimeToNextMatch Stream error is ${e.toString()}"));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e)
    {
      debugPrint("Failed with error '${e.code}': ${e.message}");
    }
     catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error while fetching TimeToNextMatch ${e.toString()}");
    }
```

I've tried pausing a few of the streams when the app is sent to background and resumed it on foreground but that did not fix the issue. As you can see, I'm also trying to log errors but for some reason the only error I constantly see when bringing the app to the foreground is [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (1049e1698) Stream error: 'Unknown: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.' Any thoughts on how this error can be caught?

Comment: "*I've been able to reproduce this issue consistently and can confirm that the this is not cause by any authentication related errors.*" You should edit the question show your [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain what you've done to debug it, including any error logs.  We should be able to reproduce the behavior using the instructions you provide. Firestore does reconnect automatically, but we can't tell what's going on without your debugging details.

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated my question - let me know if you have any thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the stream to a one time get and noticed that the issue takes place in that case as well. This means it is not related to the snapshot / stream. Per the logs I also see the following errors: "Socket is not connected" and "Could not register as server for FlutterObservatoryPublisher. Check your network settings and relaunch the application." Looks like the OS is killing the Firebase Socket after some inactivity. Shouldn't the SDK be inherently reestablishing a connection or should I do that explicitly?

Comment: hi @AlokShah, did you find a solution for your problem?
I also face this issue on iOS only, people are complaining that the app is going in background(they open navigation app or something) then return back and is not syncing. Unfotunatelly on my side there are no errors, is like the Firestore is just not returning a response.